# AdSense on pages for logged in users with different content for each user

Tags: google-adsense, authentication, google-adsense-policies, user-generated-content

Is it possible to show AdSense to logged in users when each user sees different content?     I'm developing an application where each user sees the content that they have entered.    The ads would be most relevant if they were directly related to that content.

A similar question was asked in the [Google product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/G-ckpqkX0zs) but it didn't get a good answer.

I don't see anything in the AdSense terms of service that would prohibit this.   Just the requirement that if I show ads on pages that are only available to logged in users, that I [give the AdSense bot a user and password to crawl](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/161351?hl=en) the content.

Would I have to create a unique URLs for each user so that the bot can crawl them separately, or is there a way to tell AdSense bot fetch different content for each user for the same URL?  Ideally I'd like users to all just see the home page URL.   The site is really just a single page application powered by AJAX.

I also assume that I'd have to put something into my terms of service saying that the ad system can see content the user entered, similar to Gmail.

Comment: Adsense suggest that you allow their bot to somehow crawl your protected pages but I don't think this is a requirement, it just results in the user seeing relevant ads. Having ads on a more dynamic page would just result in Adsence serving non relevant ads.

Comment: I'd sure like to show relevant ads.   You don't make much money if the ads are not relevant and the users don't click on them.

Comment: For clarification, are we talking similar to a form generated with a unqiue ID etc. So that the users unique ID/data matches which would create a meta tag with keywords for that specific page (based on the users preferences in app) which the logged in crawler would pick up?

Comment: I've created an online to-do list. http://doozoon.com/   A user logs in and sees their tasks they have entered.  If their tasks include  "fix the TV" I would like them to see relevant ads like those for new TVs.

Comment: Stephen@Google ads will not going to display TV related ads on your site, no matter, advertising running tv related ads on adwords. Google mostly show ads on interest based, for example, recently I visit some website related to seo tools, then I will see most of ads seo tools related in most of sites, even in recipes website. Yes, Google allowed to disable interest based ads from setting, but it will harm your income as hell, since advertiser get good result from interest based ads.

Answer (score 1):

There is only Difference of permission to Google Bots to Access After Locked area to show ads.

Otherwise, everything remains same.

You can Choose how Ads show on site. interest based or content based mainly.

But I personally Found that Google Shows Mix up of both on a webpage. Some IB and Some Content related.

user mostly click on those in which they have interest. and it is best for Publisher as well as Advertiser

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/99376?hl=en

> **The crawler will attempt to access URLs only where our ad tags are
>   implemented**.
>
> Only pages displaying Google ads should be sending requests to our
>   systems and being crawled.

I don't think you need to create separate URL for each user, because I have seen some websites(checkout some popular dating site) display ads on same URL like www.example.com/messages/ and display different content for each user who logged in.

Comment: Google AdSense Bot doesn't re-crawl the same URL every time it displays ads.     Users may get different ads based on re-targeting or user history, but unless you can get the bot to crawl the page for each user, I don't see how AdSense would use content matching to serve appropriate ads based on what is on the page.

Comment: Stephen@I don't know about other countries, but as a Indian user, I see 90% Ads are interest based, there are lot's of thread on webmasterworld forum, which talk about interest based ads, and it beneficial to advertiser and publisher . Adsense Bot may be not crawl same URL again and again, but it will always look on content before ads served to user, and Adsense bot did not just look into content, it also analytic how ads serve to user, and it helps to adsense team to provide better performance and optimization. Some of Information is also passed to Google Analytic tool.